# Some apps not updating when adding a new version - Google Android Management API

Tags: google-play-console, android-management-api

We have a problem with some apps when we update version in our Mobile Device Management (MDM) which use Google Android Management API.

The user must go to the Google Playstore from his device and click on "update", so isn't a "silent update".

Here, we can see that the last version added in Google Play Console (and in the MDM) is 1.0.29 but it is always 1.0.26 that is installed in the MDM :

[image]

However, the device policies are ok in our MDM but the new version doesn't install on the device. The accessibleTrackIds in the policies (first code lines) is the same as the Google Playstore which contain the new version (second picture, the trackId is at the end of the URL)

```js
{
    name:"enterprises/XXXXXXX/devices/XXXXXXX"
    policyName:"enterprises/XXXXXXX/policies/XXXXXXX"
    appliedPolicyName:"enterprises/XXXXXXX/policies/XXXXXXX"
    appliedPolicyVersion:"91"
    lastPolicySyncTime:"2022-07-29T11:34:42.232Z"
    lastStatusReportTime:"2022-07-29T11:34:57.050Z"
    policyContent:{
        name:"enterprises/XXXXXXXX/policies/XXXXXXX"
        version:"91"
        applications:[
            0:{
            packageName:"com.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX"
            installType:"FORCE_INSTALLED"
            managedConfiguration:{...}
            accessibleTrackIds:[
                0:"4701669245689423402"
            ]
            }
        ]
}
```

[image]

Does anyone have a solution for us ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried setting the **AutoUpdateMode** to **AUTO_UPDATE_HIGH_PRIORITY** in the application policy if it will work?

Comment: yes we tried but we still have the problem